# ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)

Tags: java, mysql, linux, tomcat6

We have deployed a war file on tomcat6. We are facing a error

```
[Sat May 17 12:26:48 2014] [error] (110)Connection timed out: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8090 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat May 17 12:26:48 2014] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Sat May 17 12:27:53 2014] [error] (110)Connection timed out: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8090 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat May 17 12:29:36 2014] [error] (110)Connection timed out: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8090 (127.0.0.1) failed
```

During this problem I am not able to telnet 8090 on server too.

This problem get solved once I restart MySql.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 10):

The solution to this is to add the "retry=0" parameter to your ProxyPass directives in your Apache HTTP server virtual host configurations so that it doesn't wait the default 60 seconds to retry.

E.g.

```
ProxyPass / http://backendserver:8080/ retry=0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the problem is the network.
For example. If the IP of the webserver is 192.168.1.1 and the other webserver is 192.168.0.100, the servers are in a different subnet range.
–
Matias Colli
Consultor IT