# AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04, reverse

To use reverse proxy with apache2 on ubuntu :

```
<VirtualHost test.com:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
ServerName test.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/test
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyPass           /login  http://127.0.0.1:8080/login
ProxyPassReverse        /login  http://127.0.0.1:8080/login
ProxyPass           /api  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api
ProxyPassReverse        /api  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api
```

i have apache2 errors

```
(111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else found an answer : [ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709832/ap-proxy-connect-backend-disabling-worker-for-127-0-0-1)

I tried, an it's working for me.

Edit your vhost in Apache

```
ProxyPass  /login  http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/ retry=0
```

Comment: Are you sure? The link you point to does mention the `httpd_can_network_connect on` SElinux boolean. That's the one that was responsible for those errors. Adding a retry=0 to my ProxyPass, the client connection doesn't get terminated (running a curl/wget, page would get fetched, then connection would stay active)

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I have executed the command below:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Comment: Note that SELinux is not enabled in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

from my side, check selinux :

```
getenforce
==> Enforcing
setenforce Permissive
getenforce
==> Permissive
```

then : service httpd restart

and define the parameter fot the next reboot vi /etc/selinux/config